# Apache2 virtual host not working

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2, webserver, virtualhost

After few days of trying to setup apache2 virtual hosts on my localhost I am seriously loosing my patience. Can you guys help me? Everything seems ok, but when I am trying to access local.droidbb.com in my browser I am getting response of

> > Unable to load page.  Problem occurred while loading the URL
> >     http://local.droidbb.com/. Cannot connect to destination.

Here are all related files (at least I think so).

**etc/hosts**  file

```
#127.0.0.1  ingress localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.0.1   local.droidbb.com
#127.0.1.1  debian.resnet.gre.ac.uk debian
#127.0.1.1  debian.local.droidbb.com debian

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**etc/apache2/ports.conf** file

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**etc/apache2/sites-available/local.droidbb.com** file

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName local.droidbb.com



    DocumentRoot /var/www/local.droidbb.com/public_html/

    <Directory />

            Options FollowSymLinks Includes -Indexes

            AllowOverride All

            Order allow,deny

            Allow from all

     </Directory>



    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">

        AllowOverride None

        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

        Order allow,deny

        Allow from all

    </Directory>



    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log



    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,

    # alert, emerg.

    LogLevel warn



    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Where is the problem? Oh and I should mentioned that I am running Linux Debian x64 on virtualbox.

Comment: I installed new machine again and now it just works. There was some problem with configuration of the apache probably. This time I didn't ticked 'install web-server' during debian installation and used apt-get install apache2 instead. 

Its running perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

Move file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/local.droidbb.com
```

to

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/local.droidbb.com
```

everything in sites-available is disabled :)

Comment: It was symlinked to sites-enabled by a2ensite command. Anyway, this problem is resolved. By erasing VM and installing Debian Wheeze :)

Answer (score 0):

Is apache running well? Is something in the error.log of apache? sounds like apache is not working properly. (possible configuration issue or anything else)

Comment: Apache is running without problem. When I am inserting http://localhost default index.html is loaded.